# Call public Java method from javascript error

Tags: java, javascript, html, django

In my Django web page I need Javascript to call a public method of a java applet.
I want to make the java applet POST some data to the DJango webserver, but to do this I need the cookie to authenticate session.
With this in mind I found out that I can call public methods of my applet from JS, so I tried it, and it failed.
I don't know which is the problem, or if I'm missing something.

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<applet name="mapGenerator"
    code="MapGenerator.class"
    archive="{{STATIC_URL}}java/MapGenerator.jar"
    width= 500 height = 300>

        <param name=numero_immagini value="{{floor.count}}">
        <param name=id value="{{building.id}}">
        {% for f in floor %}
            <param name=immagine{{forloop.counter0}} value="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{f.link.name}}">
            <param name=numero_piano{{forloop.counter0}} value="{{f.numero_di_piano}}">
        {%endfor%}
</applet>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        document.mapGenerator.setCookie(document.cookie);
    }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
```

Class MapGenerator:

```
public class MapGenerator extends JApplet {

    //... variables

    public void init() {
        numero_immagini = Integer.parseInt(this.getParameter(N_IMMAGINI));
        id_building = Integer.parseInt(this.getParameter(ID_BUILDING));
        images = new BufferedImage[numero_immagini];
        floors = new int[numero_immagini];

        for(int i=0; i< numero_immagini; i++) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), this.getParameter(IMMAGINE+i));
                    images[i] = ImageIO.read(url);
                    floors[i] = Integer.parseInt(this.getParameter(PIANO_IMMAGINE+i));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    public void setCookie(String cookie) {
        this.cookie = cookie;
        ed.cookie = cookie;
        System.err.println(cookie);
    }

    public void start() {

        ed = new Editor(this.getContentPane(), images, floors, id_building);                     
        this.add(ed.getPanel());
        Toolkit kit = this.getToolkit();
        Dimension dim = kit.getScreenSize();
        this.setBounds(dim.width/4, dim.height/4, dim.width/4, dim.height/4);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

When I open this web page, this is the error in JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLAppletElement> has no method 'setCookie'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe that was such a stupid thing...

I only have to put the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        document.mapGenerator.setCookie(document.cookie);
    }
</script>
```

BEFORE the applet... I'm going to cry...